# WebSocketOptions ignores receive buffer size

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket

My websocket client needs to send over a large message containing a base64 encoded image. Now, this is quit slow at the moment, and I thought... well maybe I should increase the ReceiveBufferSize of my websocket server within ASP.NET Core 2.0.

Unfortunately... it seems to completely ignore my set buffer size...

Reading through the documentation this is the only way to set the ReceiveBufferSize, that I found:

```
WebSocketOptions webSocketOptions = new WebSocketOptions()
{
    ReceiveBufferSize = 8192
};
app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);
```

The connection starts using a ApiController passing the HttpContext to a 'Service' containing this method:

```
public async Task Register(string hub, HttpContext httpContext)
{
    if (httpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        WebSocket webSocket = await httpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();

        await _websocketServer.StartJoinHubWithId(webSocket, "hub", hub);
    }
}
```

And then passing it to a WebsocketHandler class which resides in a seperate written library, containing this method *Get ready for some eye bleach*:

```
private async Task ReadHandler(WebSocket socket, string hub, string clientId)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    try
    {
        int mode = 0;
        string partialReceived = "";
        while (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            _isrunning = true;
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

            if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
            {
                _isrunning = false;
                await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            else
            {

                if (result.EndOfMessage)
                {
                    if (result.MessageType == 0)
                    {
                        string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);

                        if (message.Length > 0)
                        {

                            if (message.Contains("PARTIAL-DATA,START"))
                            {
                                mode = 1;
                            }
                            else if (message.Contains("PARTIAL-DATA,END"))
                            {
                                OnWebsocketMessageReceived(partialReceived, hub, clientId);
                                partialReceived = "";
                                mode = 0;
                            }

                            switch (mode)
                            {
                                case 0:
                                    if (!message.Contains("PARTIAL-DATA"))
                                    {
                                        OnWebsocketMessageReceived(message, hub, clientId);
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    if (message.Contains("PARTIAL-DATA,"))
                                    {
                                        if (!message.Contains("PARTIAL-DATA,START") &&
                                            !message.Contains("PARTIAL-DATA,END"))
                                        {
                                            partialReceived = partialReceived + message.Substring(13);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Debug.WriteLine(
                                            "ERROR, PARTIAL DATA DID NOT START WITH PREFIX: PARTIAL-DATA, OR HAS START OR END IN ITS PREFIX");
                                        mode = 0;
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }
        }
        await Stop(hub, clientId);
    }
    catch (WebSocketException e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Websocket client closed without calling abort.");
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        await Stop(hub, clientId);
    }
}
```

In the end, it results in this:

[image]

And from previous testing, I can tell that only part of the send string is being received.

This tells me that it still uses the default 4 kb buffer. And I have no clue on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/3206 Issue resolved, It was me all along.

Answer (score 0):

That property is obsolete. (.net 6.0)

[image]